# What is the data threshold limit in Google Analytics 4 (while using Google Signals)?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Google Analytics 4 (GA4) applies data thresholding to data pulled from their API in an effort to protect user privacy. This means if the count of users for an event is below a certain limit, GA4 will withhold that data (also called thresholding).

When ingesting data from the API, we have found that the data is subjected to data thresholding due to the use of Google Signals. When attempting to determine the specific limit for data thresholding to apply, we found that the limit is somewhere between 35-40. It appears to change randomly. According to [Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9383630?hl=en), the limit is set within the system, but they do not define what that limit is. Others have postulated it is closer to 50. (See [here](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/thresholding-applied-in-google-analytics-4-do-this/))

We have tried pulling data daily, weekly, monthly, and yearly and still find ourselves subjected to data thresholding. We would like to know the limit to bring it back to our customers to tell them what the theoretical bounds for a margin of error are.

NOTE: We would prefer to not get rid of Google Signals.

Comment: Can you please help me to understand what use case you are trying to solve with this information?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible to contain unthresholded user information.

I had a similar issue, and realised that pulling in userTotal caused mine to be thresholded. I ended up removing it and using Sessions instead, which gave a close enough approximation.

Try removing metrics/dimensions from your request one by one to identify the ones that are causing the issue, and try get by without them.

If you need them, perhaps pull a sampled and unsampled report, and add an estimated column based on the sampled data to your unsampled export.

Answer (score 0):

The simple fix for us was to stop trying to load `screenPageViewsPerUser` from the API. We weren't using it yet but were still requesting it, and it was causing the data to be massively thresholded (thresheld?). Once we removed that metric, the data came back unthresholded. You might just make sure you're not trying to load any "PerUser" metric in your request.